# In an ERD what makes an entity "optional" vs "required"?

Tags: diagram, erd

As I understand it, the white dot indicates "optional" while the black dot means "required".

If so, a Category is required while a Classified is optional.

But what does that actually mean in the database - to say that a Category is required and a Classified is optional?

[image]

Comment: You should really ask this as a suplemental to your original question, by editing the original question text.

Comment: But since the question has been answered, I assume it will not be read much any more unless someone searches for that topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the child of the relationship (in the example above set as "classified"), is optional then the column is defined with the database as allowing null records. i.e set to NULL. This means that you can either specify no records as being linked from classified to category, or many records.

Comment: "or many records" -> do we know from the dot that it permits a "many" relationship?

Comment: no - it is from the "crows feet" on the line that we know it is a many relationship. Actually looking at the diagram shows that category to classified is a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it could mean the difference between a foreign key being allowed to be `NULL` or not.

In other cases it might be something you need to check via constraints or application code.

Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with the notation used in the diagram you post so I can't tell you what it means there.